# How do I remove \listoffigures from the header of the page

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm writing my thesis using texmaker and here is my problem: as you can see from the screenshot of my pdf file, after the first page with the title "Introduzione" (Introduction), on the header of the second page there is written "Elenco delle figure" (List of figures in italian) instead of "Introduzione". I can't find a way to change it. 
Below you can find all the package used and the related commands.
This is the first time I make a question in this forum, so please tell me if you need more informations or if I did something wrong.

Thank you all in advance!

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside, titlepage]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\hypersetup{linktocpage,colorlinks=false}
\pagestyle{fancy}\addtolength{\headwidth}{20pt} 
 \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}} 
 \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection \ #1}{}} 
 \cfoot{} 

 \rhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\leftmark}]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}} 
 \lhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\rightmark}} 

\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\mainmatter
\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduzione}
```

Comment: A normal \chapter will do it.  \markboth{}{} will set the headers blank.

Comment: you haven't shown a usable example but why do you need `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduzione}` ? the chapter opening should set the table of contents and solve the problem in the question of resetting the mark for the page head so it says  Introduzione rather than list of figures.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - I think he wants to make the introduction an unnumbered chapter.  There is probably a missing \chapter*{Introduzione} etc.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks a lot! I solved the problem with \markboth{}{}

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comments.